# Next.js (React) & ScrollMagic

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scrollmagic, next.js

I would like to implement an animation to fade sections, like in [this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/extensions/fading-effect.html), into my application. Therefore I've had a look at fullPage.js.

However, since I need to integrate it into a [Next.js](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) React app with server-side rendering I can't use it since it relays on jQuery, which doesn't support SSR. Therefore I've tried my luck with [ScrollMagic](http://scrollmagic.io/), which doesn't relay on jQuery. But it also doesn't support SSR (needs `window`), therefore I've initialized it in the `componentDidMount()` method and even loaded it there (like it's recommended [here](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/219#issuecomment-258966784)).

It currently works initially, but as soon as you change the page and an AJAX request is done and Next.js replaces the page, an error will be thrown (see below):

> Node was not found

[image: Node was not found React error when using ScrollMagic with Next.js]

I've tried to destroy ScrollMagic before the AJAX request in `componentWillUnmount()`, but with no luck. I can't figure out what's wrong and unfortunately, I couldn't find any documentation about ScrollMagic with React or Next.js.

This is my entire component:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class VerticalSlider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.ScrollMagic = null;
    this.controller = null;
    this.scenes = [];
    this.container = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.container.current) {
      // Why "require" here?
      // https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/219#issuecomment-393939863
      // We can't render the component server-side, but we will still render
      // the HTML
      // eslint-disable-next-line global-require
      this.ScrollMagic = require('scrollmagic');
      this.initScroller();
    }
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.scenes.forEach(scene => {
      scene.destroy();
    });
    this.controller.destroy();
    this.scenes = [];
    this.controller = null;
  }

  initScroller() {
    try {
      this.controller = new this.ScrollMagic.Controller();
      if (this.container.current !== null && this.container.current.children) {
        [...this.container.current.children].forEach(children => {
          const scene = new this.ScrollMagic.Scene({
            triggerElement: children,
            duration: window.innerHeight * 1.5,
            triggerHook: 0,
            reverse: true
          });
          scene.setPin(children);
          this.scenes.push(scene);
        });
        this.controller.addScene(this.scenes);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.container}>
        {this.props.sections}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

VerticalSlider.propTypes = {
  sections: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.node).isRequired
};

export default VerticalSlider;
```

Comment: Which version of Next.js are you using?

Comment: Next.js version ^6.0.3

Comment: This is probably not a good answer for SO but I thought maybe this would help. React has a really good and well maintained transition library called [`react-transition-group`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group) and Next.js has a similar library called [`next-page-transitions`](https://github.com/illinois/next-page-transitions/blob/master/README.md). There is a good [example](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-next-page-transitions) showing how to use it. Example uses `_app.js` for easily animating every page transition. I suggest you to take a look at tha

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that's not what I need.

Comment: can you reproduce it here https://repl.it/site/languages/nextjs?

Comment: seems to be working https://repl.it/@code4aman/RegalFarawayBlogclient

Comment: @amankkg Yes, it works initially. But, like mentioned in my post, as soon as you have multiple pages it no longer works. Also, the VerticalSlider component shouldn't be a page component.

Comment: It would be great if you can provide us a broken example. I updated my repl.it example to demo a navigation also. Anyway, there is nothing special with nextjs and scrollmagic using together and VerticalSlider seems to be working. However, I slightly refactored it.

Comment: I found this module on npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/scrollmagic-with-ssr maybe it helps

Answer (score 3):

Would [fullpage.js](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage#server-side-rendering) not be more suited for you needs?

You should be able to map your routes and then build each slide as a placeholder for the page using the app.js

Otherwise, I should have a working example of scroll magic, I will look for the repo and share it once found.

*UPDATE:* Here is an [example](https://github.com/alvarotrigo/react-fullpage/tree/master/examples/next) of next.js using fullpage.js

> However, since I need to integrate it into a Next.js React app with server-side rendering I can't use it since it relays on jQuery

fullpage.js no longer depends on jquery and it supports SSR as well.

Answer (score 1):

Although in some other venues people suggested using next/dynamic and importing the ScrollMagic library with the option 'ssr:false', I did not have success with this tactic. The ScrollMagic object was not returned correctly.

What ended up working for me was to use a modified version of the ScrollMagic library (modified by Jan Fischer: https://github.com/bitworking) in which the whole ScrollMagic library is wrapped "in a self invoking function so that I can mock the window and document object." I copied this modified ScrollMagic to my next.js project and referenced it instead of including the package as a node module.

Here is the modified file:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitworking/react-scrollmagic/master/src/lib/scrollmagic.js

Answer (score 1):

You can get scroll magic to work with next.js by doing a dynamic import.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const load = async () => {
      if (typeof window !== undefined) {
        const ScrollMagic = (await import('scrollmagic')).default;
        const controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

        new ScrollMagic.Scene({
          triggerElement: '#one',
          triggerHook: 0.5,
          reverse: true,
        })
          .on('enter', function (e: any) {
            console.log('enter');
          })
          .on('leave', function (e: any) {
            console.log('leave');
          })
          .addTo(controller);
      }
    };
    load();
  }, []);
```